# Border not being applied to div within jstl in jsp

Tags: css, jsp, jstl

How can I apply a right border to div with contains a `<c:forEach` block ?

In below jstl code I'm attempting to display a border to right of `<c:forEach` block . The border is not being displayed. The css seems to work with just a div (no jstl code) :

```
<div class="verticalLineRight">
myborder
</div>
.verticalLineRight {
    border-right:solid #6E6A6B;
    border-width:100px;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/F23s9/1/

But when I wrap the div around a `<c:forEach` block the border isn't being displayed :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tag Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="border-right:solid #6E6A6B; border-width:10px; ">
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
   Item <c:out value="${i}"/><p>
</c:forEach>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think u define your div display inline-block live demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/F23s9/2/

Comment: You have a closing `</p>` tag after `Item <c:out value="${i}"/>` is this a typo? If not, it is probably causing your problem due to invlid HTML markup. If this is not the problem, then please post a fiddle which has the code you are having problems with, rather than just showing us code that is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 <div style="border-right:1px solid #6E6A6B; border-width:10px; ">
  <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
   <p>Item <c:out value="${i}"/><p>
</c:forEach>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot the opening stray <p>